# Django: TemplateSyntaxError-Could not parse the remainder

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-queryset

My template gets a queryset named qs.value sent from the views.py, I can display the value using {{qs.value}} anywhere in the template, but using it in an if statement raises an error.

```
    {% if {{qs.value}} > 0 %}
             <!--do something-->
             <h3 class="text-success">{{qs.value}}</h3>


    {% else %}
            <!--do something else-->
            <a href=""><button class="btn btn-primary">Else</button></a>

 {% endif %}
```

The error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '{{qs.value}}' from '{{qs.value}}'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No `{{ }}` inside of `{%  %}`.

Comment: That's right @KlausD. code worked after removing {{ }}, thank you +1

Answer (score 4):

`{{ }}` are used to get the string representation of the variable/fuction. `{% %}` are used to make some code working. Both can read variables/functions as they are passed with context without any additional `{{`/`{%` inside them because they process given arguments directly.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means you've forgotten a closing quote somewhere in the template you're trying to render. For example: `{% url 'my_view %}` (wrong) instead of `{% url 'my_view' %}` (correct). In this case it's the colon that's causing the problem. Normally you'd edit the template to use the correct `{% url %}` syntax.